# How do type a function in python based on the return value of a method on an instance passed in?

Tags: python, type-hinting

In TypeScript, I can define a function such that the return value is different depending on the behavior of an instance that was passed into the function. (See the example below.)

How can I do something similar in Python?

```js
class DocumentSuperClass {
   

}
class DocumentA extends DocumentSuperClass {}
class DocumentB extends DocumentSuperClass {}
// ... many more sibling classes

class SuperClass {
    doc: DocumentSuperClass

    meth() {
        return this.doc;
    }
}

class A {
    doc: DocumentA

    meth() {
        return this.doc;
    }
}

class B {
    doc: DocumentB

    meth() {
        return this.doc;
    }
}
// ... many more sibling classes

function a<T extends SuperClass>(input: T) {
    return input.meth() as ReturnType<T['meth']>;
}

const instanceOfDocumentA = a(new A());
const instanceOfDocumentB = a(new B());
// ... same behavior for many more sibling classes
```

Comment: try typing `from __future__ import braces` to try and parse this snippet!

Comment: basically, there is no equivalent to `ReturnType<T['meth']>` in python's type annotations

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options:

### Use `@overload`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import overload

@dataclass
class A:
    val: int

@dataclass
class B:
    val: str


@overload
def a(arg: A) -> int: ...
@overload
def a(arg: B) -> str: ...

def a(arg: A | B):
    return arg.val


typed_as_int = a(A(123))
typed_as_str = a(B("abc"))
```

The return types depend on what's passed in:

```py
Foo().one()         # -> Tuple[Any, ...] | None
Foo().one('tuple')  # -> Tuple[Any, ...] | None
Foo().one('dict')   # -> Dict[str, Any] | None
```

### Use generics

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def foo(arg: T) -> T:
    return arg

foo(1)      # -> int
foo('bar')  # -> str
```

another alternative:

Could use `Union[]` type, but that makes your function return the union type as well, not the actual runtime type.

Comment: I'd note that another option is [single-dispatch function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

Comment: I believe even if `singledispatch` is used to handle the "input type", would still need one of the mechanisms above to properly type the return value.

Comment: @BTables not really, this question is about *type annotations*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga single dispatch uses type annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize now that I wasn't quite specific enough about what I was looking for. I've updated the original question to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I still think you need to be more specific about what the Python should do/look like. Since you don't have such constraints, I've only updated my `@overload` example to better match your TypeScript example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'singledispatch' for functions or 'singledispatchmethod' for class methods.

Also, this code passes mypy checks, so code's typing annotations are fine.

```
from functools import singledispatch

class A:
    def meth(self):
        return 'a'
    
class B:
    def meth(self):
        return 1
    
C = A | B

@singledispatch
def function(input_: C):
    pass
@function.register
def _(input_: A) -> str:
    return input_.meth()
@function.register
def _(input_: B) -> int:
    return input_.meth()

print(function(A()))
print(function(B()))
```

```
a
1
```

Comment: this does not address the question, which is about type annotating the function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated my code, does it address the question?

Comment: I updated the original question above to be more specific about what I'm looking for. I think this answer gets close, but what if I want to support an arbitrary number of possible classes being passed in, as shown in the new question?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work. It's odd to me that I'm not defining the return type explicitly. But if I just leave it undefined, the type hinter seems to figure things out:

```
class DocumentSuperClass:
    pass

class DocumentA(DocumentSuperClass):
    pass

class DocumentB(DocumentSuperClass):
    pass

class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.doc = DocumentSuperClass

    def meth(self):
        return self.doc

class ClassA(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.doc = DocumentA()

    def meth(self):
        return self.doc

class ClassB(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.doc = DocumentB()

    def meth(self):
        return self.doc

def func(input:SuperClass):
    return input.meth()


instanceOfDocumentA = func(ClassA())
instanceOfDocumentB = func(ClassB())
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Figure out what?